# How to connect a jack stereo microphone to an USB-C iPad

Tags: ipad, audio, usb, microphone

I have an electric piano which has two stereo jacks to connect headphones. I would like to connect one of the jacks to an iPad as an input device.

Are there any Jack-to-USB-C microphone connectors that work with an iPad? What is the correct expression to search for? Searching for "Jack USB-C" only yields results for headphones which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: You need an *audio interface* for an iPad

Comment: Could you edit this to specify which jack(s) are relevant for your problem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microphone_connector

Comment: There are two problems to solve here: getting an audio interface for your iPad, and making sure it can work with a headphone output.

Comment: iPad/iPhones etc only have a single [i.e. mono] mic input using 'standard' hardware. You're going to have to up the ante considerably to get dual-channel input at line/instrument signal levels. Perhaps something like this - https://www.thomann.de/gb/ik_multimedia_irig_pro_duo_i_o.htm [not strictly a recommendation, as I've never used these myself, but IKMultimedia are a well-respected manufacturer of this type of interface].

Comment: btw, going that route you will still probably need a splitter from the keyboard, TRS to dual TS.

Comment: @bmike The piano has two 6.3" stereo jack outputs

Comment: @tetsujin It does not necessarily have to be stereo. That would be nice, but first of all I would like to get any tone from my piano to my iPad. The primary reason is to get the learning software recognize the tones I play while I can simultaneously wear headphones

Comment: @thinkr I assumed that adapter won't work, as it's a headphone adapter... if this actually works, that might just be the solution that I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you have a piano with two ¼” headphone jacks.  Below is an image of mine; I have a ¼“ to 3.5mm adapter so I can use regular (Bose) headphones with my piano shown here.

[image]

Usually, with electronic pianos, there is a MIDI interface.  This is how I connect my iPad; by using the Lightning to USB3 adapter. If you have a MIDI port on your piano, you can use that interface pretty easily and very inexpensively. You just need the [Apple USB-C to USB adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MJ1M2AM/A/usb-c-to-usb-adapter)

However, if you need to interface the sound output directly into your device, you need an audio interface (like a mixer) that connects to your iPad; the [PreSounus Audiobox Go](http://radnex.us/Presonus_Audiobox_Go) should meet your needs rather inexpensively (approx. $80USD).

It has a USB-C interface and can accommodate both  ¼“ and 3.5mm jacks as well as both microphone/instrument and line level inputs. This is something you can’t do with the USB-C headphone adapter.

<sup>Disclaimer:  I’ve used PreSonus products in professional settings with their 8 and 16 channel mixers, but haven’t used their “home” gear.  However, from my experience, I wouldn’t hesitate recommending them.</sup>

Comment: Ah, they're the other guys. The name wasn't coming to me when I added my comment above. Behringer probably also make something down in the affordable bracket too.

Comment: I found this - a bit click-bait, but all manufacturers I know already. Might be OK as a list of possibles - https://musiccritic.com/equipment/best-ipad-audio-interface/ I've never used any of these consumer-level interfaces either, so no specific recommendation from me.

Comment: @Tetsujin I love me some Behringer  and  they do have an is202 (iStudio) but it is a whole iPad dock which is probably way overkill ($$$) for this application but probably an awesome bit of kit.

Comment: I have a friend works as a producer at the BBC. Last time I went to visit him, he seemed somewhat embarrassed by the fact that some of the studios there now had Behringer 32-ch boards. I've actually never used one , but they do seem to be trying hard to undercut everybody else. [last time I was engineering at the beeb they still had the old Calrecs from the 60s;)

Comment: @Tetsujin That level of equipment is above my paygrade!  I never did anything like broadcast level - most was voice recording and the odd instrument here and there.  The broadcast folks I  worked with recommended PreSonus and Behringer which is how I learned about them.  They work well and are built like tanks.

Comment: Long time ago, but I was lucky enough to have worked in some of the big studios in London & elsewhere in the UK… way, way back in the 80's. The places where the price of a board always ended in 'hundred grand'. These days, I'm more in the 'hundred quid' bracket. Times have changed ;)

Comment: You mean i’m not alone in that budget range @Tetsujin?  It sounds like you’ve got some good tales to tell.  Wouldn’t mind hearing them over a few pints!

Comment: haha. Yup, my current interface is a Line6 from about 20 years ago - sounds great; amp sims built in. The pint idea sounds fabulous. I'd write a book, but it wouldn't be anywhere near as star-studded as such as Guy Pratt's [which you should read] - I didn't work with Madonna, Pink Floyd & Michael Jackson. I was more Pete Waterman & Musical Youth ;))

Comment: @Tetsujin Wait, Musical Youth of “Pass the Dutchie” fame?

Comment: Yup. I played keyboards on that - still makes me, ooohhh… a couple of hundred quid a year. I won't be retiring to a mansion in the country on that any time soon ;))

Comment: @Tetsujin, good tuned  and downing some pints is a good life. For a mansion in the countryside maybe we could look up Clarkson’s Farm….

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145947/discussion-between-tetsujin-and-allan).

Comment: Thanks! MIDI was the first thing I tried, but it turns out that the piano has USB, but no MIDI over it, sadly :-(

Comment: Mine is USB as well, try connecting that using the USB-C to USB adapter I linked. If that doesn’t work, return it and go for the Presonus.

Comment: Yes, that's the first thing I tried. I ended up buying a M-Audio M-Track Solo, as it was the cheapest audio interface that was available here.

Thanks to all for the hints and tips!

Comment: Glad you were able to get it sorted!